# How to set the selected option from ajax call on page load angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

How to set the selected option from ajax call on page load
i get the zones by ajax call
so i want to trigger the change function of zones on page load and set the selected option of the cities  select box
My snippet code:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="zone_id" ng-model="zone_id" name="zone_id" ng-change="getSearchCities(zone_id)">
    <option>Choose zone</option>
    <option value="20" selected>Zone 1</option>
    .....
  </select>

  <select class="form-control" name="city_id">
    <option>choose city</option>
    <option value="{{ city.city_id }}" ng-repeat="city in cities">
    {{ city.name }}
    </option
  </select>


  <script>
    var SApp = angular.module('searchApp', []);
    SApp.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.getSearchCities = function(zone_id) {
        // alert(zone_id);
        $http.get("zones.php?zone_id="+zone_id).then(function(response) {
          $scope.cities = response.data.city;
        });
      }
    }); 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer finally and it is simply :
1-Use ng-options instead of ng-repeats the option tag 
2-call the function getSearchCities
    $scope.getSearchCities($scope.zone_id);